# My Spring Boot app cannot see the Thymeleaf templates

Tags: spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I have a Spring Boot app, where i define my thymeleaf dependency in pom.xml with these lines:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

So when i start the application and print the predefined bean names, i see these beans (which i think are important for thymeleaf to run properly):

- templateEngine
- thymeleafResourceResolver
- thymeleafViewResolver

The project structure looks like this:

[image]

I have defined some fragments inside the fragments.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">

  <body>

    <div class="container" th:fragment="copy">
        <hr>
        <footer>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <p>Copyright &copy; Teamtool 2015</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </footer>
    </div>

  </body>

</html>
```

.. and i am trying to use those from my index.html like this:

```
<!doctype html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
<title>Hello AngularJS</title>
<base href="/" />
<link href="css/angular-bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
<style type="text/css">
[ng\:cloak], [ng-cloak], .ng-cloak {
    display: none !important;
}
</style>
</head>

<body ng-app="hello" ng-cloak class="ng-cloak">
    <div ng-controller="navigation" class="container">
        <ul class="nav nav-pills" role="tablist">
            <li ng-class="{active:tab('home')}"><a href="/">home</a></li>
            ...
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div ng-view class="container"></div>

    <div class="col-md-3" th:include="fragments :: copy"></div>

    <script src="js/angular-bootstrap.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    ...
</body>
</html>
```

But my template is not added in the index.html. What do i do wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Application scans Thymeleaf templates in `templates` folder, move index.html to `templates` that should work.

Comment: i see a Whitelabel Error Page, my index.html is not seen inside the templates folder.

Comment: It should, if you are using spring boot you don't have to configure anything, at least if you don't want to override something, so check if you annotated controller with `@Controller` and have something like this in your controller class `@RequestMapping(value = "/")
    public String indexPage() {
        return "index";
    }`, then check in `index.html` and `fragments.html` if you closed all tags properly as `<div>` or `<hr>` or even `<link>` should be closed `<link></link>` or `<link/>`, and last one `<div ng-view ></div>` is not allowed in thymeleaf, use `<div ng-view=""></div>`.

Answer (score 0):

I try to be generic here, Spring boot considers static folder as public resources folder that it uses to serve **static** files from. As you are telling spring boot to also configure a templating system - thymeleaf in your case - it will start looking in templates folder. Thymeleaf templating is not static but a **dynamic** page building mechanism.

Now because you configured thymeleaf Springboot expects that you want to render dynamic thymeleaf template and its looking for a starting point from within templates folder. It does not find index.html file showing you a Whitelabel page. When you move index.html to template folder it has a default starting point. You can map any other file name as stating point to your application by mapping a URL path like  @RequestMapping(value = "/") in one of you controller.

You can use static folder to serve angular JS files, but a template has to be in templates folder, unless you override it.